# Facebook Graph API - How to post to wall, with new lines?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm playing with Facebook Graph API and I am facing one problem - I can't find any way how to post to wall with some HTML code `or` new lines. How it could be done? 
Here's my code

```
<?php
include_once 'lib/facebook.php';
define("FACEBOOK_APP_ID", '10126');
define("FACEBOOK_API_KEY", '064ca1988b');
define("FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY", '9afdf92114');
define("FACEBOOK_CANVAS_URL", 'http://apps.facebook.com/my_canv_app/');
if (isset($_GET['code'])){
    header("Location: " . FACEBOOK_CANVAS_URL);
    exit;
}

$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID, 'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
                'scope'  => 'email,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location,user_about_me,user_hometown'
        )
);

if (!$user) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
    exit;
}


try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    $statusUpdate = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array('message'=> 'Trying to make new line here \n <br /> Neither works', 'cb' => ''));
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
}
?>
```

how could I do it?

Comment: you might want to remove the api/secret key from the code example (not sure if someone can do anything with this).

Comment: I edited it before, real code is more than 32 chars long

Comment: Ah ok, didn't know they had to be 32 chars long in every case :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't include any markup or new lines in wall posts. You used to be able to provide some FBML markup to get some basic formatting, but that got abused. If you could include html and new lines, Facebook profiles would start looking like MySpace profiles.

Facebook pretty much sanitizes all wall/profile content, for security reasons.

Comment: hmm, that's bad. But some applications, like this - http://lulzimg.com/i23/18cd3a.png does include link. how ?

Comment: There are a number of ways to get links into the feed. But you have to use Facebooks data structures. My guess is they are using the "properties" attribute of the post. That will give you a list of links, each one on a new line. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Answer (score 6):

This works.

```
try {
$uid = $facebook->getUser();
$me = $facebook->api('/me');
$statusUpdate = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array('message'=> 'Line 1
                                                             Line 2
                                                             Line 3
                                                             Line 4',
                                                         'cb' => ''));
```

Comment: Haha. We're all looking for html answers and Facebook's just like dude, press enter, we'll honor that. Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is your solution `%0A` insert it in your text and it will act as a line break :)

Comment: Thanks, this made a line break for me!

Answer (score 2):

Despite all the stuff that’s been said in answers to previous questions regarding newlines in wall posts – I never had any problem with just using the escape character `\n` when making posts using PHP.

> ```
> array('message'=> 'Trying to make new line here \n <br /> Neither works', …
> ```

Of course, if you are filling you message parameter in PHP using **single** quotes, \n means only the two characters \ and n – that these escape sequences are only interpreted when using *double* quotes, is *absolutely basic PHP syntax knowledge …*

*D’oh!*

Answer (score 0):

put this

> < center >< /center >

to where you want to break the line

ex:

line1< center >< / center >line2< center >< / center >line3

NOTE: no spaces before and after < >

Answer (score 0):

For those who would like an update on this.
I am using the PHP SDK and \n works as long as it is enclosed in double quotes (""). Single quotes won't work.

So, I fetch my data from a tiny mce box and I do this:

```
$message = preg_replace("/<br \/>/","\n",$tiny_mce_message); // the \n must be in ""!
$message = strip_tags($message);
$this->message = utf8_encode($message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Newline character (ASCII code 10) does the trick.